# Unifying endpoints with different JSON providers in Apache CXF with Spring

Tags: spring, cxf, jax-rs

**Background**

We are using [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) 2.5.x , [JSR 311 1.1.1](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html) , and [Spring 2.5.x](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/)

We currently have 2 endpoints, ABC and DEF, that use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) as the JSON provider. Our Spring file looks something like:

```
<bean id="jacksonMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
<bean id="jsonProvider"class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" p:mapper-ref="jacksonMapper"/>

<jaxrs:server id="service1" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="resourceABC" />
        <ref bean="resourceDEF" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers >
         <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Using annotations on the Java classes, these endpoints are available via `http://company.com/api/rest/ABC` and `http://company.com/api/rest/DEF`

**Challenge**

We want to introduce a new endpoint, IJK, that uses [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) as a JSON provider. We would like the endpoint to map to `http://company.com/api/rest/IJK`.

**Note**: Indeed, it is trivially easy to map to `http://company.com/api/rest/new/IJK` by using a different endpoint, but we'd like to avoid that.

**Approaches**

We've tried defining a new server with the same address:

```
<jaxrs:server id="service2" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="resourceIJK" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers >
         <ref bean="gsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

but that doesn't work. We've tried using multiple `providers` in the same `server` element, but no dice.

[This link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAXRSservicesincontainerwithSpringconfigurationfile.) discusses using `serverFactories` elements. Such as:

```
<beans>
  <jaxrs:server id="customerService" address="/service1">
    <jaxrs:serviceFactories>
      <ref bean="sfactory1" />
      <ref bean="sfactory2" />
    </jaxrs:serviceFactories>
  </jaxrs:server>

  <bean id="sfactory1" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.SpringResourceFactory">
     <property name="beanId" value="customerBean1"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="sfactory2" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.SpringResourceFactory">
     <property name="beanId" value="customerBean2"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="customerBean1" class="demo.jaxrs.server.CustomerRootResource1" scope="prototype"/>
  <bean id="customerBean2" class="demo.jaxrs.server.CustomerRootResource2"  scope="prototype"/>
</beans>
```

This looks promising, but how to set the JSON `provider` for the services, `customerBean1` and `customerBean2` in Spring?

**Question**

Can someone clarify the last approach above, with serviceFactories? Can we achieve the goal of introducing `resourceIJK` (at the *same* endpoint root) with Gson instead of Jackson?

If it can be done only with Apache CXF 2.7, that is OK and useful info.

Comment: Hi! Facing the same problem. How did you end up solving this?